# Python cliente / servidor

Tags: python, python-2.7

Estoy haciendo un cliente y un servidor con sockets.

El cliente envía una opción (1,2,3) y el servidor le retorna el resultado.
En la opción 1 envío un comando (ipconfig) y me devuelve el resultado, pero después para volver a ejecutar otro comando he de volver a pulsar 1, y seguidamente el nuevo comando.

¿Como puedo hacer para que cuando pulso la opción 1 me permita enviar comando y recibir el resultado infinitas veces, sin salirse al menu principal como hace ahora?

#### Servidor principal.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import logging
from lib.thread_server import Thread_server
from app_settings import settings
logger = logging.getLogger(settings.LOGGING['logger_name'])
import socket

''' Metodo main '''
def main():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind(("127.0.0.1", 9999))
    s.listen(2)

    while True:
        sc, addr = s.accept()
        t_server = Thread_server('Thread_server',sc)
        t_server.start()
    s.close()

''' Inicio de la app '''
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

#### Hilo servidor.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import logging
import threading
import time
# Import configuration file:
from app_settings import settings
# Instance logger:
logger = logging.getLogger(settings.LOGGING['logger_name'])
import os
import subprocess
from lib.thread_1 import Thread_1


class Thread_server(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, name, sc):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name
        self.sc = sc

    def run(self):
        while True:
            message_recived = self.sc.recv(1024)
            # Condiciones.
            if message_recived == "1":
                while True:
                    # recivo.
                    mensaje1 = self.sc.recv(1024)
                    print(mensaje1)
                    # envio.
                    self.sc.send('correcto')
            elif message_recived == "2":
                print('opcion 2')
            elif message_recived == "3":
                break
            else:
                self.sc.send('Opcion no valida.')
        self.sc.close()
```

#### Cliente.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import logging
from app_settings import settings
logger = logging.getLogger(settings.LOGGING['logger_name'])
from lib.thread_1 import Thread_1
import socket
import os 
import time
import sys

def main():
    PORT = 9999
    SERVER = "127.0.0.1"
    SERVER_STATUS = "STOP"
    TIME_WAIT_CONECTING = 1

    while True:
        try:
            # Si el servidor esta encendido.
            s = socket.socket()
            s.connect((SERVER, PORT))
            SERVER_STATUS = "START"
            os.system('cls')
            # Salgo del bucle y doy paso al menu de opciones.
            break
        except Exception:
            os.system('cls')
            print('CONECTING SERVER')
            SERVER_STATUS = "STOP"

    while True:
        print('====== SERVER OPTIONS ======')
        print('- PRESS 1 - Enter comand. ')
        print('- PRESS 2 - ')
        print('- PRESS 3 - EXIT.')
        print('============================')
        # Instanciamos una entrada de datos para que el cliente pueda enviar mensajes.
        mensaje_menu = raw_input("SEND SERVER >> ")

        if mensaje_menu =="1":
            while True:
                mensaje_servidor = raw_input("SEND COMAND >> ")
                # Envio comando.
                s.send(mensaje_servidor)
                mensaje_recivido = s.recv(1024)
                print("SERVER RESPONSE >> " + mensaje_recivido)

        if mensaje_menu =="2":
            mensaje_servidor = raw_input("SEND COMAND >> ")
            # Envio comando.
            s.send(mensaje_servidor)

        if mensaje_menu == "3":
            break

        os.system('cls')

    s.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Lo que veo raro es que en el Hilo servidor, luego del `if message_recived == "1":` tienes un `while True:` del que nunca sales.

Comment: Si el while es el que me muestra el menu "principal" por decirlo de alguna manera.Con 3 opciones.Y lo que quiero conseguir es que cuando entre en la opcion 1 me mantenga en otro bucle en el que pueda mandar un comando se ejecute y me devuelva el resutado,.. así hasta que con un comando determinado me devuelva al menu principal y pueda elegir por ejemplo la opcion 2 del menu principal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que no estableces un protocolo de feed-back correcto con el servidor, nunca le envías la opción que eliges en realidad y tampoco detienes la escucha de comandos por parte del servidor. Un posible protocolo podría ser:

1. Cliente envía la opción al servidor ("1").
2. El servidor debe responder a esta informando de que entra en el ciclo para ingresar comandos hasta que se le ingrese una palabra clave. Esta clave debe ser algo que no sea un comando, por ejemplo `@stop`.
3. El cliente envía mensajes hasta que el servidor le diga que no está a la escucha de comandos (por un error o porque se le ha enviado la clave `@stop` por parte del cliente.)

Existen muchas formas de hacerlo y va a depender en gran medida de como quieres que se responda a excepciones tanto por parte del cliente como del servidor. La idea de todas formas es esta, comunicarte con el servidor mediante palabras clave que permitan alterar su estado.

El código debería ser algo así:

**Cliente:**

```
while True:
    print('====== SERVER OPTIONS ======')
    print('- PRESS 1 - Enter comand. ')
    print('- PRESS 2 - ')
    print('- PRESS 3 - EXIT.')
    print('============================')
    # Instanciamos una entrada de datos para que el cliente pueda enviar mensajes.
    mensaje_menu = raw_input("SEND SERVER >> ")

    if mensaje_menu == "1":
        s.send("1")
        mensaje_recibido = s.recv(1024)
        if mensaje_recibido == "@start":
            print("Servidor a la espera de comandos, ingrese @stop para salir...")
        else:
            print("Error")

        while True:
            mensaje_servidor = raw_input("SEND COMAND >> ")
            s.send(mensaje_servidor)
            mensaje_recibido = s.recv(1024)
            if mensaje_recibido == "@stop":
                break
            print("SERVER RESPONSE >> " + mensaje_recibido)
```

**thread_server.py**:

```
def run(self):
    while True:
        message_recived = self.sc.recv(1024)
        # Condiciones.
        if message_recived == "1":
            self.sc.send('@start')
            while True:
                # recivo.
                mensaje1 = self.sc.recv(1024)
                if mensaje1 != "@stop":
                    print(mensaje1)
                    self.sc.send('correcto')
                else:
                    self.sc.send('@stop')
                    break
```

Para la opción 2 o subsiguientes estableces un protocolo similar.

**La salida sería algo así:**

```
====== SERVER OPTIONS ======
- PRESS 1 - Enter comand. 
- PRESS 2 - 
- PRESS 3 - EXIT.
============================
SEND SERVER >> 1
Servidor a la espera de comandos, ingrese @stop para salir...
SEND COMAND >> ipconfig
SERVER RESPONSE >> correcto
SEND COMAND >> cd
SERVER RESPONSE >> correcto
SEND COMAND >> ping
SERVER RESPONSE >> correcto
SEND COMAND >> @stop
====== SERVER OPTIONS ======
- PRESS 1 - Enter comand. 
- PRESS 2 - 
- PRESS 3 - EXIT.
============================
SEND SERVER >> 1
Servidor a la espera de comandos, ingrese @stop para salir...
SEND COMAND >> ipconfig
SERVER RESPONSE >> correcto
SEND COMAND >> @stop
====== SERVER OPTIONS ======
- PRESS 1 - Enter comand. 
- PRESS 2 - 
- PRESS 3 - EXIT.
============================
SEND SERVER >>
```

Comment: Es lo que necesito, muchas gracias amigo.Ya funciona bien.